# How can I get a background image displayed behind content?

Tags: css, background-image, background-position, background-size

I am creating a chat app with visual studio and want to add a background image on the home page and about us page, both pages already have a nav-bar and the home page has a box where the user can enter details and join the chatroom and I want to add an image behind all of that, I tried using different codes but the one that came close is this one:

HTML

```html
<img src="image/friends.jpg" alt="image">
```

CSS

```css
div {
  background: url('image/friends.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

However the image is not shown in full it just shows the image icon and it removes the content, please help

Comment: Try changing the z-index.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing right but remove this line from your HTML.

```
<img src="image/friends.jpg" alt="image">
```

You are already giving the `div` a background image from your CSS, keeping the `img` tag will add the image again and that on top of the content.

---

You should also **use CSS background-image on body** instead if you want the image to be the background of the whole page.

```
body {
  background-image: url('image/friends.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to target the body itself.

in your css instead of doing this:

```
div {
background: url('image/friends.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}
```

do this:

```
body {
background: url('image/friends.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-image` css property. No need to provide any additional additional `img` element in your html for this purpose.

```css
div.bg  {
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/cinqueterre.jpg");
  background-color: #cccccc;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <h1>The background-image Property</h1>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need

```
<img src="image/friends.jpg" alt="image">
```

Just use CSS:

```
body {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542281286-9e0a16bb7366");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center; // if you want the image to be centered
}
```

or (see snippet)

```
.bg {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542281286-9e0a16bb7366");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center; // if you want the image to be centered
}
```

```css
.bg  {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542281286-9e0a16bb7366");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

div {
  height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
I am creating a chat app with visual studio and want to add a background image on the home page and about us page, both pages already have a nav-bar and the home page has a box where the user can enter details and join the chatroom and I want to add an image behind all of that, I tried using different codes but the one that came close is this one...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello beginner here as well. if you or anyone else come across this issues like I did as well, I used this link ( https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ ) for a helpful CSS code on having my photo in the back ground. When it came to having the Nav background in front of the photo, I simply added nav to the selector and it did the trick. Not sure if this is right but it worked for me

Comment: can you please remove the link and add the code that fix the issue in your answer